# manage font-size on different browser

Tags: html, css, browser

Just like I have mentioned in the title.

How do you guys manage the fonts , when you do a web design

because different browsers even you set equal in pixel but the result seems to be different.

It makes  other element collapse with the things I have designed.

so please advice me.

Eg: most browsers are okay , but IE is bad.The fonts appear to be very big than in others.

Comment: have use some sort of reset.css? so all the elements have the same value :)

Comment: Welcome to the dark side of web design, where ancient relics of browser wars still fall from the skies suddendly and unpredictably and may destroy your whole life without warning!

Answer (score 0):

For main body text, you don't. Some people want bigger text so they can read it more easily; get in their way at your peril. Use relative font sizes in units such as ‘em’ or ‘%’.

For small amounts of presentational text where you need text size to match pixel-sized on-screen elements, use the ‘px’ unit. Don't use ‘pt’ - that only makes sense for printing, it'll resize more-or-less randomly when viewed on-screen.

You can still never get the text exactly the same size because fonts differ across platforms—and Lucida Grande and Helvetica look very different of course.